# How to take FileZilla credentials from the software's interface?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

Hi I use FileZilla to transfer files to the server via FTP.

I connected to FileZilla from my computer months ago. I entered the server address, port & administration password on to the startup window of the software & checked the "Always connect to this server" option ON. So, every time I start FileZilla, It connects to my server automatically & I never had to remember my credentials.

I know it's in the software itself..somewhere...like in a cache memory or something. I need to get those details. How can I take those credentials from the FileZilla client installed in my desktop pc.? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this file:

> C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\recentservers.xml

or one of the other xml files in the folder. You can open tham with any text editor, the passwords are plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the password, you can read the XML file in

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml

otherwise you can use [Filezilla Password Decryptor](http://securityxploded.com/filezilla-password-decryptor.php) with following steps :

**Step 1.** Launch Filezilla Password Decryptor after completion of installation.

**Step 2.** Next click on '**Start Recovery**' button and all ftp login passwords stored by SmartFtp will be recovered.

**Step 3.** By default passwords are not shown for security reasons as it is sensitive data. However you can click on '**Show Password**' button at the bottom to view these passwords.

Answer (score 0):

To take server credentials from FileZilla Client installed in a pc,

visit:

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server Interface.xml

Open the .xml file in notepad. You will see a file similar to this with server credentials you are looking for.
[image]