# How to take server credentials from FileZilla client installed in my pc?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

Hi I use FileZilla to transfer files to the server via FTP.

I connected to FileZilla from my computer months ago. I entered the server address, port & administration password on to the startup window of the software & checked the "Always connect to this server" option ON. So, every time I start FileZilla, It connects to my server automatically & I never had to remember my credentials.

I know it's in the software itself..somewhere...like in a cache memory or something. I need to get those details. How can I take those credentials from the FileZilla client installed in my desktop pc.? Is it even possible?

Here's an image.

[image]

Comment: Have a look in `%AppData%\Roaming\FileZilla\SiteManager.xml` to see if it's stored it as a new profile... I think it's in `Roaming`!?

Comment: Let me have a look at it. @Big Chris

Comment: same question here : http://superuser.com/questions/825937/how-to-take-filezilla-credentials-from-the-softwares-interface

Comment: Please don't delete questions when they're duplicates. We can close them as such and make them easier to discover that way